# Scaling Spring WebFlux with Tailable ReactiveMongo

Tags: mongodb, scale, spring-webflux, reactive

I am building a server sent events endpoint that will keep open connections for a long period (1h+) continuously sending events in realtime. I am using reactive Mongo to share all DB updates between all application instances. As far as I see on each HTTP request, a new Mongo connection is open. This is not salable because DB connection pool is limited. Using defaults starts to crash at 500 http requests (500 open SSE http connections => 500 DB connections).

How can I make this scalable to handle 50000+ simultaneous http requests per instance using the Tailable query? Strangely I didn't find anything online regarding this issue. Is there any feature built in the java mongo driver to share queries on one connection?

Simply, this is the code I am testing with: a simple GET endpoint that returns a Flux of records from a Tailable MongoDB query:

```
//controller endpoint
@GetMapping(value = "location/{id}", produces = MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM_VALUE)    
Flux<Location> getLocationById(@PathVariable String id) {
    return locationsRepository.findById(id)
}
```

and

```
//repository
@Repository
public interface LocationsRepository extends ReactiveCrudRepository<Location,String> {
    @Tailable
    Flux<Location> findById(String id);
}
```

Mongo has default configurations and of course `location` is an indexed capped collection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying out different solutions, I have managed to implement a totally scalable solution for the problem using Redis-Streams. Where each API request `{id}` would match a different Stream in Redis-Streams. And a continuous Redis Puller would pull data from Redis by adding/removing Streams to the query in realtime while event-streamed requests are being opened/closed to the API.

More details about the implementation: https://medium.com/takeaway-tech/scaling-reactive-apis-764205866a5e